# añadir contenido a un json anidado (sin que sea al final) en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

tengo este json :

```
{
      "listaUsers": {
        "test": {
          "Nombre": "nombretest",
          "Apellidos": "apellidotest",
          "password": "test"
        },
        "test2": {
          "Nombre": "nombretest2",
          "Apellidos": "apellidotest2",
          "password": "test2"
        }
      },
    
      "otralista": {
        "clave": "valor"
      }
}
```

podria de algun modo añadir objetos json dentro de listaUsers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inicialmente tal vez deberias replantear la estructura del JSON. Existen dos llaves en la jerarquía más alta de la estructura que son `listaUsers` y `otralista`, como su nombre específican, son listas y su representación más cercana en el formato JSON es un Array. Corrigiendo lo anterior la correcta representación sería:

```
{
      "listaUsers": [
        "test": {
          "Nombre": "nombretest",
          "Apellidos": "apellidotest",
          "password": "test"
        },
        "test2": {
          "Nombre": "nombretest2",
          "Apellidos": "apellidotest2",
          "password": "test2"
        }
      ],
    
      "otraLista": [
        "clave": "valor"
      ]
}
```

Siguiendo con esa lógica y pensando en que ya tienes esa estructura en forma de diccionario en python, la forma de agregar un nuevo usuario es a través de:

```
# Cards el JSON en el json_dict a través de json.loads, json.load o alguna otra alternativa
# ...
json_dict['listaUsers'].append(nuevoUsuario)
```